# Python How to hide traceback in unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

guys, I have a unittest was where I don't want to throw exception when find one but wait until the end and output raise it at the end.:

```
from unittest import TestCase
class TestA(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_lst(self):
        a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        b = [1, 3, 3, 5, 5]
        total_errs_count = 0
        total_errs_msg = []
        for i in range(5):
            try:
                self.assertEqual(a[i], b[i])
            except AssertionError:
                total_errs_count += 1
                total_errs_msg.append(f'Index {i}, Expected {a[i]}, Get {b[i]}')
        if total_errs_count > 0:
            for m in total_errs_msg:
                print(m)
            raise AssertionError("Test Failed")

test = TestA()
test.test_lst()
```

I got:

```
IOndex 1, Expected 2, Get 3
Number 3, Expected 4, Get 5
----------------------------------------------------
AssertionError     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-b70dc996c844> in <module>
     27 
     28 test = TestA()
---> 29 test.test_lst()

<ipython-input-5-b70dc996c844> in test_lst(self)
     24             for m in total_errs_msg:
     25                 print(m)
---> 26             raise AssertionError("Test Failed")
     27 
     28 test = TestA()

AssertionError: Test Failed
```

However, the desired output is to hide the traceback:

```
Index 1, Expected 2, Get 3
Index 3, Expected 4, Get 5
----------------------------------------------------
AssertionError: Test Failed
```

How can I hide the traceback in this case? Another post suggested to catch the exception by `unittest_exception = sys.exc_info()`, but here I don't want to immediately throw the exceptions but wait for all test cases to finish.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: All cases are already tested. You just raise an error because you kept track of errors on array. total_errs_msg > 0 so you raise an error? Why you just don't use regular unittest. Unittest keep track of your errors. There is no need to use try expect in your testcase.

Comment: @HalilİbrahimYıldırım I am not sure how to. If I just do it without try and except. The test break when it find the first exception, rather than collection all.

Comment: I added an example, I hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
from unittest import TestCase
import unittest


class TestA(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_lst(self):
        a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        b = [1, 3, 3, 5, 5]
        for i in range(len(a)):
            with self.subTest(i=i):
                self.assertEqual(a[i], b[i])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: subtest is great! Thank. But do you also know how to hide trackback within the python file. I know in terminal I can do $pytest --tb=no

Comment: import sys
sys.tracebacklimit = 0
is what you are looking for?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Are you using Jupyter notebook?

Comment: No not really. I am writing a .py test file.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/ThirstyInbornProspect I just did here? Can you  check? Does it match with your output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212871/discussion-between-halil-brahim-yildirim-and-j-yang).